# Construct MySQL query ( meta_key/meta_value table)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've got table like:

```
id | meta_key | meta_value
-------------
1 | color | red
1 | price | 10
2 | color | red
2 | price | 20
3 | color | blue
3 | price | 10
```

how can I get all unique ids were color=red and price=10 . Can I get it with single simple query, w/o pivots etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like to approach these using `group by` and `having`:

```
select id
from t
where (meta_key = 'color' and meta_value = 'red') or
      (meta_key = 'price' and meta_value = '10')
group by id
having count(distinct meta_key) = 2;
```

An alternative is a `join`.  If there a no duplicate values for an `id`:

```
select id
from t tc join
     t tp
     on tc.id = tp.id and
        tc.meta_key = 'color' and tc.meta_value = 'red' and
        tp.meta_key = 'price' and tp.meta_value = '10';
```

The `group by` method has the advantage of scalability and expressibility.  It is easy to express many conditions (color is not red, manufactured in US or China) that are not simple equality.  Also, additional conditions have very similar performance.

The second probably performs better (with the right indexes) on a couple of conditions.

Comment: Solution with `group by` works fine for me. Thanks a lot.