# Mysql query that finds dates for the previous month from meta_value

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have created a view called acquity_fields with 4 columns (see also view from phpMyAdmin attached):
meta_id; post_id; meta_key; meta_value

I was using this post [Construct MySQL query ( meta_key/meta_value table)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36101969/construct-mysql-query-meta-key-meta-value-table) to help me to create a query so that I can pull the last month (e.g Sept 1-30 inclusive) as well as August for number of clients.

But I need to **walk** first so I wanted to display **all** months with number of clients in each then add in the additional statements for last month and previous.

Here is the query I put together for getting all the months and clients,

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as Clients, MONTHNAME(FROM_UNIXTIME(meta_key = 'wpcf-acquity-date')) as Month 
FROM acquity_fields 
WHERE (meta_key = 'wpcf-acquity-date') 
GROUP BY Month
```

but it seems to be putting all the clients into one month and displaying it as:

```
Clients    |   Month
----------------------
  399      |  January
```

I am not sure if its the time conversion, but I am stumped to what is causing this. Any help would be great and thanks in advance!

[View acquity_fields in phpmyadmin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gdyhi.png)

Answer (score 0):

In your select part of the query, FROM_UNIXTIME() takes in a timestamp, so try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as Clients, MONTHNAME(FROM_UNIXTIME(meta_value)) as Month 
FROM acquity_fields 
WHERE (meta_key = 'wpcf-acquity-date') 
GROUP BY Month
```

(meta_key = 'wpcf-acquity-date') is a WHERE condition, not a timestamp integer. If you have something that's not a timestamp, the system will treat it as a default date, and the output will become December or January depending on your settings.

Comment: Thanks @danielhj that worked well to display all the months!

Comment: No prob :) Good luck with your development!